# Overflow visible in Expanded widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

My layout is a row with three expanded widgets.

I need overflow visible in one of the expanded widgets

This is the code

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(color: Colors.red,)
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: Container(color: Colors.green,)
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: Container(color: Colors.orange,)
    ),
  ],
),
```

Now I need to add circles like this, in of the Expanded widgets, that overflow the Expanded widget. I can't wrap the Expanded in an overflow box, so I am lost

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I tried this with the third expanded, just to see if it will overflow, but it only overflows the SizedOverflowBox, no overflow over the Expanded

```
Expanded(
  flex: 3,
  child: SizedOverflowBox(
    size: const Size(100.0, 100.0),
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
    child: Container(height: 50.0, width: 1500.0, color: Colors.blue,),
  ),
),
```

It looks like it is not going to be possible

Comment: What exactly do you mean by overflow?  Do you just want the dots to be positioned along the edges?

Comment: Just inverse the wrapping order and wrap the OverflowBox in Expanded widget

Comment: @ScottGodfrey there are titles inside the expanded with a circle, like a bullet that overflows the container. They are bullet points

Comment: @dm_tr and how do I position it that way?

Comment: @dm_tr I think this will overflow the box, but not the Expanded

Comment: @user3808307 IMHO its still not clear what you want to achieve. Do you have any live example to show. Please describe what is overflow in this context means. Then show an example of the overflowed widget. If its text that is overflowing, give an example of that. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 2):

Can easily be achieved with a Stack. Please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                )),
            Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                )),
            Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                )),
          ],
        ),
        Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 15,
                    width: 15,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 15,
                    width: 15,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 15,
                    width: 15,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Please see the code for Text Bullet points overflowing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red.withAlpha(60),
            child: OverflowBox(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              maxWidth: 400,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                child: Text(
                  'HelloHello ',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green.withAlpha(60),
            child: OverflowBox(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              maxWidth: 400,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    '\n\nHelloHello HelloHello \n\nHelloHello HelloHello \n\nHelloHello HelloHello \n\nHelloHello HelloHello ',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.purple.withAlpha(60),
            child: OverflowBox(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              maxWidth: 400,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                child: Text(
                  '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello ',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes but the exact position of the circles depends on dynamic content inside the Expanded widgets, if I do it like this the position will be independent of what is in the expanded, right?

Comment: With this code the circles will always be in the Center of the screen. But with Stack and Positioned widget you can position the circles anywhere you like. The circles are being added last so they will always be `on-top` of all other widgets and will always be visible.

Comment: thank you but it's really not what I need, the circles are bullet points in the text, and I would have to calculate the exact position of the text to add them. I will use this as a last resource .

Comment: I mean vertical position

Comment: I have not fully understood what you are trying to do, but from what little I could understand I have added code to overflow text. To make the overflowing text visible the container colors need to have some level of transparency.